# Angular scopes and binding data to a directive

Tags: angularjs

Consider

```
angular.module('App').directive('errors',function() {
return {
restrict: 'A',
controller:function() {
   var self = this;
   self.closeErrors = function() {
      self.errors = [];
      self.hasErrors = false;
   }
},
controllerAs: 'errorsCtrl',
templateUrl: 'errors.html'
}
```

when called with

```
<div errors="otherCtrl.errors"></div>
```

the object errors comes from another controller.
I know i can add

```
scope: {errors:"="},
```

and then access it in my controller via

```
$scope.errors;
```

but  when I assign it to

```
self.errors = $scope.errors.
```

self.errors never gets updated when it is changed in the parent.

So my question is, how can I let this work that whenerver my parentcontroller changes the errors object it is also changed in the errorsCtrl.

(Also I do know I can access errors directly in my template without the controller, but I simply want to use my errorsCtrl)

Comment: Why don't you just use $scope for every variable in the controller then?

Comment: As far as I read since 1.4 they try to get rid of $scope and especially for 2.0 so I want to do it with the var self = this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `bindToController: true` to your directive.

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html

> Angular 1.3 introduces a new property to the directive definition
>   object called bindToController, which does exactly what it says. When
>   set to true in a directive with isolated scope that uses controllerAs,
>   the component’s properties are bound to the controller rather than to
>   the scope.
>
> That means, Angular makes sure that, when the controller is
>   instantiated, the initial values of the isolated scope bindings are
>   available on this, and future changes are also automatically
>   available.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed to know :)